# How to remove varying multiple strings from a string extracted from a csv file

Tags: python, string, list

I am quite new to programming and have a string with integrated list values. I am trying to isolate the numerical values in the string to be able to use them later.

I have tried to split the string, and change it back to a list and remove the EU variables with a loop. The initial definition produces the indexes of the duplicates and writes them in a list/string format that I am trying to change.

This is the csv file extract example:

```
Country,Population,Number,code,area
,,,,
Canada,8822267,83858,EU15,central
Denmark,11413058,305010,EU6,west
Southafrica,705034,110912,EU6,south
```

We are trying to add up repeating EU number populations.

```
def duplicates(listed, number):
    return [i for i,x in enumerate(listed) if x == number]

a=list((x, duplicates(EUlist, x)) for x in set(EUlist) if EUlist.count(x) > 1)
str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in a)

for x in range (6,27):
    str2=str1.replace("EUx","")
    #split=str1.split("EUx")
#Here is where I tried to split it as a list. Changing str1 back to a list. str1= [x for x in split]
```

This is what the code produces:

```
('EU6', [1, 9, 10, 14, 17, 19])('EU12', [21, 25])('EU25', [4, 5, 7, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 23, 24])('EU27', [2, 22])('EU9', [6, 13])('EU15', [0, 8, 26])
```

I am trying to isolate the numbers in the square brackets so it prints:

```
[1, 9, 10, 14, 17, 19]
[21, 25]
[4, 5, 7, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 23, 24]
[2, 22]
[6, 13]
[0, 8, 26]
```

This will allow me to isolate the indexes for further use.

Comment: Please add a sample of the csv file

Comment: Added a CSV file example. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Nice. You want to sum population per area?

Comment: Yes. The answer below works to fix the result. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure without example data but I think this might do the trick:

```
def duplicates(listed, number):
    return [i for i,x in enumerate(listed) if x == number]

a=list((x, duplicates(EUlist, x)) for x in set(EUlist) if EUlist.count(x) > 1)
for item in a:
    print(item[1])
```

At least I think this should print what you asked for in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use pandas module and save some typing. Remove the four commas on second line and then:

```
import pandas as pd
csvfile = r'C:\Test\pops.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
df.groupby('membership')['Population'].sum()
```

Will output:

```
membership
Brexit      662307
EU10         10868
EU12        569219
EU15       8976639
EU25      17495803
EU27        900255
EU28         41053
EU6       13694963
EU9         105449
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It definitely makes it much shorter.